Sprinboot no encuentra un bean
Tengo el siguiente mapper
@Mapper
@Component
public interface PriceEntityMapper {

    @Mapping(source="brandId", target="brandId")
    @Mapping(source="startDate", target="startDate", qualifiedByName = "timestampToLocalDateTime")
    @Mapping(source="endDate", target="endDate", qualifiedByName = "timestampToLocalDateTime")
    @Mapping(source="priceList", target="priceList")
    @Mapping(source="productId", target="productId")
    @Mapping(source="priority", target="priority")
    @Mapping(source="price", target="price")
    @Mapping(source="curr", target="currency")
    Price priceEntityToPrice(PriceEntity priceEntity);

    @Named("timestampToLocalDateTime")
    default LocalDateTime timestampToLocalDateTime(Timestamp timestamp) {
        return timestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}

y la siguiente implementacion:
@Service
public class PriceServiceImpl implements PriceService {

    private final PriceRepository priceRepository;
    private final PriceEntityMapper priceEntityMapper;

    @Autowired
    public PriceServiceImpl(PriceRepository priceRepository, PriceEntityMapper priceEntityMapper) {
        this.priceRepository = priceRepository;
        this.priceEntityMapper = priceEntityMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Price getPrice(LocalDateTime applicationDate, Integer productId, Integer brandId) {
        try {

            //PriceEntity priceEntity = priceRepository.findByBrandIdAndProductIdAndStartDateLessThanEqualApplicationDateAndEndDateGreaterThanEqualApplicationDate(brandId, productId, Timestamp.valueOf(applicationDate));
            return priceEntityMapper.priceEntityToPrice(new PriceEntity());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Price not found", e);

        }
    }
}

Cuando intento levantar la aplicación me dice esto:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.dharian.application.service.PriceServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.dharian.infraestructure.mapper.PriceEntityMapper' that could not be found.

No lo entiendo ya que tengo las anotaciones @Mapper and @Component, tambien tengo esto en mi clase main:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.dharian.infraestructure","com.dharian.application"})
public class PruebatecnicaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PruebatecnicaApplication.class, args);
    }

}

pero sigue sin encontrar los beans.
Por si sirve de algo, uso IntelliJ.

¿Estás usando mapstruct? Si es así, prueba a anotar la interfaz del mapper con @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
